# Node.js Probot actions on new merge and PR

Tags: node.js, github, github-api, probot

1. On new merge into main, try to merge the latest changes into feature/* branches
2. On any new PR against main / update to PR, check if the PR template is filled up as expected, if not mark the PR status as failed

I am new to Probot and working on a GitHub app in node.js. How can I perform the above tasks?